# Is there a way to stall loading of certain resources in window onload event to improve site performance?

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a website build using Vue.js.

It has several mp4 videos, one of the being full-width full height on the first screen with some text on top of it. It also has a loader screen.
Right now this kind of action determines when the loader is to be removed.

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        removeLoader();
    });
```

The problem is that on some mobile devices it takes about 20 seconds to load every resource (every video and image) and then remove the loader.

I thought of doing something like this.
Just to wait for the loading of the first video and then removing the loader. But `loadeddata` event firest too soon and as a result, the only thing which is visible for half of a second is a video without text.
Plus I have a logic for a situation when video cannot be autoplayed to display an image instead of a video. So I'm not sure this will work anyway.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].addEventListener('loadeddata', () => {
                removeLoader()
            })
        }, 500)
    })
```

So I'm not sure if there a way to load everything but the rest of the videos in onload event? Or is there any other way to improve site performance in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

@Allan, i think you need **not display** video and text components at all (by adding class with css `display: none` with or with opacity, if it will be any problems) until video component fires `loadeddata` event. At that moment you remove loader and show these two simultaneously - what is your target.

Hope this helps.

Comment: And as you said, if video cannot be loaded in 2 sec., for example, loading stops and instead of it there will be displayed image. Or may be you wish display this image (with beginning of movie) in 'background' of animated loader.

Comment: In this case, you will not need loader screen - and dont display to user, that video is still loading ;)